# How to configure SSL client for Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

The only option that I can find for configuring the SSL configuration is `spring.data.cassandra.ssl=true/false`. We need to configure a key store and trust store to enable two-way SSL between the client and the cluster.

Is this possible out of the box or do I need to configure the cluster manually with my own `@Configuration` object?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote everything in the application.properties file

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:xyz.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=xyz
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-alias=xyz
```

Comment: I tried the equivalent with javax.net.ssl.* and didn't work. Not sure that this is a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bean CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer  to populate SSL details.
Build your own SSLContext using truststore and keystore.

```
  @Bean
  public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer cqlSessionBuilderCustomizer() {
      return cqlSessionBuilder -> {
        try {
            cqlSessionBuilder
                      .withSslContext(buildContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```